# Summary section in a Sharepoint List page

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have a sharepoint list with multiple columns. At the top left of the page, I want to present a summary section by doing some calculations

For example, in this list, I want to create a box at the top like this.
When I use the default aggregate functions, it is just giving total at the bottom of that column, but i want to total doing some condition. How may I do this? kindly advice - I'm not a SP developer - so is there a simple way to do this via sharepoint online without writing complex code

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is no easy out of the box SharePoint way to add such info at the top of a list view. An approach without writing code might go like this:

- Create a new page on the site. Don't mess with the original list view
- on the page, show the list part and use filters to hide unwanted items. Group by something and collapse the group so only the total row is visible, then use another list web part underneath the collapsed view. This still looks ugly, but is fast and requires no coding.
- Or, create a PowerApp that pulls the data and performs the calculations you want
- add the PowerApp in a web part at the top of the page

Comment: thanks a lot teylyn. Do you have a reference link how can i create a powerapp page?

Comment: You don't. You create a modern page. Then you add a web part for PowerApps and point to the PowerApp you have created in PowerApps. The web part for PowerApps is in the list of web parts that you see for modern pages.